# Comparing variables to all items in list in Python

Tags: python

I need to write a function for an edx Python course. The idea is figure out the number of letters and words in series of strings and return the average letter count while only using for/while loops and conditionals. My code comes *close* to being able to do this, but I cannot. For the life of me. Figure out why it doesn't work. I've been bashing my head against it for two days, now, and I know it's probably something really simple that I'm too idiotic to see (sense my frustration?), but I do not know what it is.

If I'm looking at line 14, the logic makes sense: if i in the string is punctuation (*not* a letter) and the previous character (char, in this case) is not punctuation (therefore a letter), it should be a word. But it's still counting double punctuation as words. But not *all* of them.

```
def averageWordLength(myString):
    char = ""
    punctuation = [" ", "!", "?", ".", ","]
    letters = 0
    words = 0
    if not myString == str(myString):
        return "Not a string"
    try:
        for i in myString:
            if i not in punctuation:
                letters += 1
            elif i in punctuation:
                if char not in punctuation:
                    words += 1
                elif char in punctuation:
                    pass
            char = i

        if letters == 0:
            return "No words"
        else:
            average = letters / (words + 1)
            return letters, words + 1, average
    except TypeError:
        return "No words"
print(averageWordLength("Hi"))
print(averageWordLength("Hi, Lucy"))
print(averageWordLength("   What   big spaces  you    have!"))
print(averageWordLength(True))
print(averageWordLength("?!?!?! ... !"))
print(averageWordLength("One space. Two spaces.  Three spaces.   Nine spaces.         "))
```

Desired output:

```
2, 1, 2.0
6, 2, 3.0
20, 6, 4.0
Not a string
No words
38, 8, 4.75
```

What in blazes am I doing wrong?!

٩๏̯͡๏۶

Final correction:

```
for i in myString:
    if i not in punctuation:
        letters += 1
        if char in punctuation:
            words += 1
    char = i
```

Comment: What are your desired outputs for these print statements?

Comment: The output(s) is supposed to be:
2.0, 3.0, 4.0, Not a string, No words, 4.75

Comment: As an aside, that's a lot of code that could be throwing erros that you are wrapping in a single try-block. You should try to make that as narrow as possible.

Comment: I've been foregoing elegance, lately, in lieu of trying to force it to work by boring my *mindthoughts* through my monitor, but you're absolutely right.

Comment: Posted my solution above. Thanks to all the great people who helped me see what I was doing wrong!

Answer (score 3):

```
else:
    average = letters / (words + 1)
    return letters, words + 1, average
```

You're adding 1 to words by default... this is not valid in all cases: `"Hi!"` being a good example. This is actually what is putting off all of your strings: Anytime a string does not end in a word your function will be off.

*Hint*: You only want to add one if there is no punctuation after the last word.

Comment: Ha! I got it to work! I didn't realize that I was taking my one-size-fits-all word counting approach (word + 1) for granted. Thanks for helping me think about it in another way.

Unf. I am a novice, and this is the most basic function ever, but I am so pleeeased right now! #satisfying

Answer (score 3):

A problem happens when the string **begins** with a punctuation character: the previous character is still `""` and not considered as a punctuation character, so an non-existent word in counted.

you could add `""` in the list of symbols, or do :

```
punctuation = " !?.,"
```

because testing `c in s` return true if c is a substring of s, aka if c is a character of s. And the empty string is contained in every string.

---

A second problem occurs at the **end**, if the string terminate with a word, it is not counted (were your `word+1` a way to fix that ?), but if the string terminate with a punctuation, the last word is counted.

Add this just after the `for` loop :

```
if char not in punctuation:
   words += 1
```

And now there will be no need to add 1, just use

```
average = letters / words
```

Comment: I wanted `"" not in punctuation` to be `False` (see line 13), everything is ok

Comment: I take back what I said. I converted punctuation to `" !?.,"` without thinking about it. You make a valid point :)

Comment: Aaaaaa, I never even *considered* that the problem would be at the beginning of the strings. I posted my solution above, but using your and @TemporalWolf 's advice, I counted words by their *beginnings* and not by their ends.

Answer (score 0):

This is made more difficult since I assume you're not allowed to use inbuilt string functions like split().

The way I would approach this is to:

1. **Split the sentence into a list of words.**
2. **Count the letters in each word.**
3. **Take the average amount of letters.**

   def averageWordLength(myString):

   ```
   punctuation = [" ", "!", "?", ".", ","]

   if not isinstance(myString, str):
       return "Not a string"

   split_values = []
   word = ''
   for char in myString:
       if char in punctuation:
           if word:
               split_values.append(word)
           word = ''
       else:
           word += char
   if word:
       split_values.append(word)

   letter_count = []
   for word in split_values:
       letter_count.append(len(word))

   if len(letter_count):
       return sum(letter_count)/len(letter_count)
   else:
       return "No words."
   ```